# What's 年度? (Comparing research results)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, academic-japanese

I'm looking at a study and it's comparing these two:
現状（２６年度）and 調査結果（３０年度）.

So it's comparing the "present condition" and the "research results" but what does the XX年度 mean?

Answer (score 4):

年度 is the financial year (or maybe academic year if it's a research paper), so 2020年度 would the the financial year of 2020. So why do the numbers look weird? I think in your example the year is measured in eras so  ３０年度 would be the 30th year of the 平成 (Heisei) era. This ended with 平成31 in 2019.